# SwiftUI and Combine what is the difference between Published and Binding

Tags: binding, swiftui, combine

I know in which situations to use `@Binding` and `@Published`

like in **ObservableObject** I generally use **@Published**, or `objectWillChange.send()`

And `@Binding` in subviews to propagate changes to parent

But here I have snippet which seems to be working that uses both `@Binding` and `@Published`
in **ObservableObject**

I consider what is the difference.

```
@Binding var input: T
@Binding var validation: Validation

@Published var value: T {
    didSet {
        self.input = self.value
        self.validateField()
    }
}

init(input: Binding<T>, rules: [Rule<T>], validation: Binding<Validation>) {
    self._input = input
    self.value = input.wrappedValue
    self.rules = rules
    self._validation = validation
}
```

As I tested it seems that if I bind TextField to @Published then didSet is called but if I bind it to @Binding then didSet won't be called.

Comment: A simple difference is @publish works for `downward` or children while @binding works for `upwards`/ parents. you can combine both together in some situation but not always necessary

Answer (score 0):

For a @Binding, I found that `didSet` was called if you assign to the property directly. Try running this example in an xcode playground:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct MyView: View {
  @Binding var value: Int {
    didSet {
      print("didSet", value)
    }
  }

  var body: some View { Text("Hello") }
}

var myBinding = Binding<Int>(
  get: { 4 },
  set: { v in print("set", v)})

let view = MyView(value: myBinding)
view.value = 99
```

Output:

```
set 99
didSet 4
```

Regarding the difference between `@Published` and `@Binding`:

- You'll generally use `@Binding` to pass a binding that originated from some source of truth (like `@State`) down the view hierarchy.
- Use `@Published` in an `ObservableObject` to allow a view to react to changes to a property.